# Issues with connection in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql, authentication, connection

Today I've installed the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express. As I know, on the start up there is a login screen where I can choose betweeen the authentication and credentials. Now I have startet SSMSE and I cannot connect to my Server(runs locally). I have tried to use my Windows account and also the "sa" account. Both doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem. I've reinstalled the SQL Server, after that it works.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This.

Comment: The "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS" is missung. There are no nodes under "SQL Server Network Configuration".